# 2nd level (drop-down) of the navigation menu not working

Tags: menus

Second level of my navigation menu (drop-down) doesn't seem to be working.

Things to note:

- It's not loading into the site (i.e. not showing in source code *image below*)
- I'm using bootstrap 4 for the layout of my theme (the menu is not bootstrap however)
- I'm trying to get prouct categories in dropdown, though other pages aren't showing either

I have spent 3 hours looking for a solution. Any idea to what the issue is would be greatly appriciated!

[image]
[image]

Comment: please inspect element and check css i think this css problem and send site name i try to inspect element and send solution for you.

Comment: Use [Bootstrap-ready Walker](https://github.com/wp-bootstrap/wp-bootstrap-navwalker) for `wp_nav_menu()`.

Comment: Problem is in your theme CSS file. Some CSS are missing for sub-menu items. Check your style.css file properly.

Comment: the issue is resolved, I had ['depth'    => 1,] and i changed it to ['depth'    => 3,]

Comment: @TimothyKA  if you have resolved your issue, then please put that as an answer, and mark it correct. That will help others that may have a similar problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I had `'depth' => 1,` instead of `'depth' => 3`. I didn't allow my nav to have more than 1 in depth essentially.

Answer (score 0):

Try to display the menu with the function [wp_nav_menu()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/) anywhere on you site , also check the depth attribute .